# SAS instream upload with input statement: string truncation

Tags: sas

I wrote this code snippet to load a data set in SAS.

```
data eser7.ateneo;
infile datalines missover;
input FAC $  AA0506  AA0607  AA0708; 
datalines;
Architettura    200 200 200
Economia    680 680 680
Giurisprudenza  -   350 400
Ingegneria  470 470 600
Lettere -   -   150
SMFN    -   -   180
ScPolitiche -   300 300
; 
run;

proc print data = eser7.ateneo;
run;
```

In the result viewer, I noticed first variable FAC has truncated string. I can't solve it setting a fixed size for FAC column, so which is the best way to adapt length dinamically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS columns have fixed sizes.  You need to set the longest possible size (through a `LENGTH` statement, generally, or using an informat on input) in order to tell SAS how much space to set aside for the column.

```
data eser7.ateneo;
infile datalines missover;
length FAC $20;
input FAC $  AA0506  AA0607  AA0708; 
datalines;
Architettura    200 200 200
Economia    680 680 680
Giurisprudenza  -   350 400
Ingegneria  470 470 600
Lettere -   -   150
SMFN    -   -   180
ScPolitiche -   300 300
; 
run;

proc print data = eser7.ateneo;
run;
```

What you can do if you are unable to determine the correct maximum size is read it in with the maximum possible size ($32767) and then either use compression (`options compress=YES;` or `options compress=CHAR;`) or post-input analyze the dataset and modify the length to a shorter size.  But you cannot have per-row lengths; compression does give you something close to VARCHAR functionality (but still needs a maximum size set) at the cost of some speed.